# set back to parameters passed to script in unix

Tags: shell, unix

I have a shell script **test** in unix that look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

set `date`
 echo 'Arguments' $*
 echo 'Argument 1:' $1
 echo 'Argument 2:' $2
 echo 'Argument 3:' $3
 echo 'Argument 4:' $4
 echo $2 $3, $6
```

Any further calls to **$number** will show arguments of the **date** command.

If I called the script like this **./test 1 2 3**, how do I get back to the parameters **1 2 3**?

Comment: It's tricky to do this robustly in sh. Have you considered processing the actual arguments before you overwrite them, or using `set` inside `( ... )` or a function so that the effect is minimized?

Comment: Do the `date` processing in a function - the command line args are then un-touched.  Alternatively if you can use bash as the shell `saved=( "$@" )` - only trick is `${saved[0]}` IS $1 - i.e. instead of being 1 indexed it's 0 indexed.

Comment: Why are you doing `set $(date)` at all? If you don't want to change the positional parameters, just delete that line.  If you want to recover the original parameters, save them before you change them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@that other guy` and `@Mr R` mentioned solutions work:

Using `set` inside `( )`:

```
#!/bin/sh

(set `date`
 echo 'Arguments' $*
 echo 'Argument 1:' $1
 echo 'Argument 2:' $2
 echo 'Argument 3:' $3
 echo 'Argument 4:' $4
 echo $2 $3, $6)

echo "\$1 is $1"
echo "\$2 is $2"
echo "\$3 is $3"
```

Using a function:

```
#!/bin/sh

date_args() {
set `date`
 echo 'Arguments' $*
 echo 'Argument 1:' $1
 echo 'Argument 2:' $2
 echo 'Argument 3:' $3
 echo 'Argument 4:' $4
 echo $2 $3, $6)
}

date_args

echo "\$1 is $1"
echo "\$2 is $2"
echo "\$3 is $3"
```

Calling **./test 1 2 3** outputs:

```
Arguments Tue Mar 23 07:10:17 PM EET 2021
Argument 1: Tue
Argument 2: Mar
Argument 3: 23
Argument 4: 07:10:17
Mar 23, EET
$1 is 1
$2 is 2
$3 is 3
```

Saving parameters for later use (also save file name that is being executed):

```
#!/bin/sh

saved=("$0", "$@")

set `date`
 echo 'Arguments' $*
 echo 'Argument 1:' $1
 echo 'Argument 2:' $2
 echo 'Argument 3:' $3
 echo 'Argument 4:' $4
 echo $2 $3, $6

echo "\$0 is ${saved[0]}"
echo "\$1 is ${saved[1]}"
echo "\$2 is ${saved[2]}"
echo "\$3 is ${saved[3]}"
```

Calling **./test 1 2 3** outputs:

```
Arguments Tue Mar 23 07:10:17 PM EET 2021
Argument 1: Tue
Argument 2: Mar
Argument 3: 23
Argument 4: 07:10:17
Mar 23, EET
$0 is ./test,
$1 is 1
$2 is 2
$3 is 3
```